# Can two subprocesses both send messages to stdout inside a Tcl/Expect script?

Tags: logging, stdout, expect

I have written an Expect script which spawns one subprocess (certbot), parses the output, then executes a second subprocess (a Python script) using data extracted from the first, and finally sends a carriage return (`\r`) to the first. I was recently debugging an issue with my script, so I thought I would add some logging to the Python script (which previously did not print any output). However, doing this caused the expect script to return this error:

```
    while executing
"exec ./test2.py "$SITE_DOMAIN" "$fileName" "$fileData""
    (file "./test.exp" line 23)
```

So then I tried changing my call to the second process / Python script from an `exec` call to a `spawn` call. This partially works and it got rid of the error. But strangely enough, I see the output from the first process right up until I start seeing output from the second process. Once the second process starts logging messages, I no longer see any output from the first.

I'm including here files to illustrate the problem as an MRE:

**main.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set SITE_DOMAIN $env(SITE_DOMAIN)
set SITE_EMAIL $env(SITE_EMAIL)

# Spawn the certbot process
spawn ./test1.py certonly -m "$SITE_EMAIL" --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renew --preferred-challenges http --manual -d "$SITE_DOMAIN" -d "www.$SITE_DOMAIN"
set certbot_spawn_id $spawn_id

# Expect the output starting with 40 hyphens and capture it
expect {
    -re {(?n)^(- ){39}-\r\nCreate a file containing just this data:\r\n\r\n([\w.-]+)\r\n\r\nAnd make it available on your web server at this URL:\r\n\r\n.+/acme-challenge/([\w.-]+)} {
        set fileData $expect_out(2,string)
        set fileName $expect_out(3,string)
    }
    timeout {
        "Error: output from certbot did not match the expected pattern"
        exit 1
    }
}

# Call a separate command with the parsed value
exec ./test2.py "$SITE_DOMAIN" "$fileName" "$fileData"

# Send Enter to the certbot process to confirm
send -i $certbot_spawn_id "\r"

# Wait for the certbot process to finish
expect eof
```

**test1.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
OUTPUT = """
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Account registered.
Requesting a certificate for example.com and www.example.com

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Create a file containing just this data:

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopq.rstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW

And make it available on your web server at this URL:

http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopq

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
"""

print(OUTPUT)
thing = input()
print("done")
```

**test2.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
from time import sleep

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig()

logger.info("Uploading file to web server")
sleep(2)
logger.info("Upload complete")
sleep(1)
```

So if you run **main.exp** as-is, you'll see the first error that I mentioned. (And if you remove the logging statements from test2.py, those errors will go away.) If you change line 22 of **main.exp** to use `spawn` instead of `exec`, that too will fix the error, but then you won't see the word `done` output by the first process. The last thing displayed will be `Upload complete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Python's `logging` prints log messages to *stderr*.
2. Expect uses Tcl and Tcl's `exec` raises error if it sees any output to *stderr*.

Example:

```
$ expect -c 'exec bash -c "echo hello >&2" '
hello
    while executing
"exec bash -c "echo hello >&2" "
```

Tcl's `exec` has option `-ignorestderr` to stop it from raising error in such cases:

```
$ expect -c 'exec -ignorestderr bash -c "echo hello >&2" '
hello
```

---

Regarding "*but then you won't see the word `done` output by the first process*", you spawned a new process and then you also need to wait for it to complete:

```
spawn ./test2.py "$SITE_DOMAIN" "$fileName" "$fileData"
expect eof
#^^^^^^^^^

send   -i $certbot_spawn_id "\r"
expect -i $certbot_spawn_id eof
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

From Tcl's `exec` [doc](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm):

> If standard output has not been redirected then the `exec` command returns the standard  output  from  the  last
> command  in  the  pipeline, unless `2>@1` was specified, in which case standard error is included as well.  **If
> any of the commands in the pipeline exit abnormally or are killed or suspended**, then `exec` will return an error
> and the error message will include the pipeline's output followed by error messages  describing  the  abnormal
> terminations;  the `-errorcode` return option will contain additional information about the last abnormal
> termination encountered.  **If any of the commands writes to its standard error file and that standard error  is  not
> redirected and `-ignorestderr` is not specified**, then `exec` will return an error;  the error message will include
> the  pipeline's  standard  output,  followed by messages about abnormal terminations (if any), followed by the
> standard error output.